# How do I do load time weaving of JSP's with AspectJ 1.6 and Tomcat 6?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, aop, aspectj

Here is my situation:

I have a web application in Eclipse. At the moment it is an AspectJ web application.

I have an aspect in my "src" folder called `JSPCSRFTokenInjection.aj` that has pointcuts to capture the `JspWriter.write` method and some other stuff. It looks like so:

```
package com.aspects; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.thesis.aop.util.StopWatch;

public aspect JSPCSRFTokenInjection{ 
Logger logger; 
StopWatch watch;

private String currentCSRFToken = null;

//Constuctor for the Aspect. I do some init of loggers and
//such here.
public JSPCSRFTokenInjection(){ 
    //PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties"); 
    logger = Logger.getLogger("csrfMitigationLogger"); 
    logger.info("CSRF Injection Aspect Created"); 
    watch = new StopWatch(); 
} 


//Capturing the CSRF Token from the request by intercepting the 
//_jspService method inside of the JSP
public pointcut csrf_jspServiceIntercept(HttpServletRequest req, 
    HttpServletResponse resp) : 
    call(public void _jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)) 
    && args(req, resp);


before(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) : 
    csrf_jspServiceIntercept(req, resp){
    currentCSRFToken = (String) req.getParameter("csrfSalt");
    logger.info("Got CSRF Token from request: " + currentCSRFToken);
}

//Pointcut and advice for capturing the writing into a JSP.
public pointcut csrf_captureFormWriting(String msg, JspWriter writer) :
    call(public void JspWriter.write(String)) 
    && args(msg) 
    && target(writer)
    && if(msg.toLowerCase().contains("</form>"));

before(String msg, JspWriter writer) : csrf_captureFormWriting(msg, writer){
    try{
        logger.info("WRITING TO JSP");
        writer.write("TEST_CSRF");
        writer.write("<input type='hidden' name='csrfSalt' value='" +     currentCSRFToken + "'/>");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

I also have an `aop.xml` file in the `WebApp/WebContent/META-INF/` directory. 
For reference my `web.xml` file is in `WebApp/WebContent/WEB-INF/` directory .

The `aop.xml` looks like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj       /dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
<weaver options="-showWeaveInfo -verbose -debug -Xset:weaveJavaPackages=true">
    <!-- Weave types that are within the javax.* or org.aspectj.*
    packages. Also weave all types in the foo package that do
    not have the @NoWeave annotation. -->
    <include within="javax.*"/>
    <include within="com.*"/>
    <include within="org.*"/>
    <include within="org.aspectj.*"/>
</weaver>
<aspects>
    <!-- declare two existing aspects to the weaver -->
    <aspect name="com.aspects.JSPCSRFTokenInjection"/>
    <aspect name="com.aspects.MitigateCSRFAspect"/>
    <!-- Of the set of aspects declared to the weaver
    use aspects matching the type pattern "com..*" for weaving. -->
    <include within="com.*"/>
    <include within="org.*"/>
    <!-- Of the set of aspects declared to the weaver
    do not use any aspects with the @CoolAspect annotation for weaving -->
</aspects>
</aspectj>
```

I am also adding the `-javaagent:C:/aspectj1.6/lib/aspectjweaver.jar` to my JVM parameters in Tomcat.

If it helps, I am using the SysDeo plugin for tomcat. Also, compile time weaving is working fine on other parts of the application, however, I am unable to weave in any of my aspects affecting JSP's.

Comment: Not completely sure but your signature could be a little wrong, it should be `call(public void *._jspService(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)` with the wildcard to represent any type

Comment: That's true too. I figured out my real issue though, my aop.xml was in the wrong place!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I was putting my aop.xml file in the wrong directory. Very stupid on my part.

It is supposed to go in the

```
<ProjectRoot>/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/aop-ajc.xml
```

directory. However, I was putting it directly under WEB-INF.